# Group By MySQL query to ignore null and pull last value

Tags: mysql, group-by, null

I'm trying to find a way to write a query that will group a ID's together and display output of the latest data removing NULLs for the previous grouped ID's data.

For example:

```
ID    |    ID2   |    ColA    |    ColB    |  ColC
---------------------------------------------------
1     |    1     |    ABCD    |     XY     |    A
2     |    1     |    NULL    |     DB     |  NULL
3     |    2     |    NULL    |     WW     |    B
4     |    2     |    DCBA    |    NULL    |    C
```

Desired output

```
ID2   |    ColA    |    ColB    |  ColC
----------------------------------------
1     |    ABCD    |     XY     |    A
2     |    DCBA    |     WW     |    C
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have't got one. If I GROUP BY, I end up with NULLs.

Comment: i.e. select ID2, ColA, ColB, ColC FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID2;

Comment: Consider providing a more properly representative data set (ideally as a set of DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle), TOGETHER WITH the desired result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have come up with an answer. I tried sqlfiddle.com but the site was down so I couldn't post it.

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT
    ID2,
    IF (LOCATE(";", TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColA ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';'))), LEFT(TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColA ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';')), LOCATE(";", TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColA ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';')))-1), TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColA ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';'))) AS LastColA,
    IF (LOCATE(";", TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColB ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';'))), LEFT(TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColB ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';')), LOCATE(";", TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColB ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';')))-1), TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColB ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';'))) AS LastColB,
    IF (LOCATE(";", TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColC ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';'))), LEFT(TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColC ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';')), LOCATE(";", TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColC ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';')))-1), TRIM(BOTH ";" FROM GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ColC ORDER BY ID DESC SEPARATOR ';'))) AS LastColC
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    ID2
```

This will concatenate all the distinct values for the grouped ID2 together separated by a semicolon ordered by ID descending, then it'll cut the grouped text up to the first semicolon (i.e. the latest/highest ID). NULLS are not concat'd and empty cells leave leading/trailing semicolons, hence the trim.

Anyone have any comments / ideas regarding this solution?

Thanks,

Marty

Answer (score 0):

Will there be no more than one non-NULL value in each column?  If so:

```
SELECT ID2,
        GROUP_CONCAT(ColA),
        GROUP_CONCAT(ColB),
        GROUP_CONCAT(ColC)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY ID2;
```

MAX() instead of GROUP_CONCAT() may work.  And it may work if there are multiple non-NULL values.  Try it.

**Edit**

Note that GROUP_CONCAT (and other aggregates) will work only if there is only one non-NULL entry per group, as your sample data shows.  If there can be multiple non-NULLs per group, then edit your example.  And state the rule for which one to pick.  The solution, then, may involve @variables.

Comment: Unfortunately, there will be more than one item per column, so I cannot use GROUP_CONCAT. MAX() shows the max calculated value, not the last item. I might try GROUP_CONCAT ordered by ID2, encased in a get last (or first) item.